# How can I use variable value as name for another variable (batch file)?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

I want to use one variable value as another variable name in command line script.
e.g:

```
set VAR1=%1
call set VAR3=JAVA%VAR1%_HOME
echo %VAR3%
```

This should print the value of system environment variable called JAVA8_HOME (C:\program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121)

How can I do it?

Comment: Simply use `call echo %%%VAR3%%%` or if delayed expansion is enabled `echo !%VAR3%!`

Comment: This type of management is fully explained at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990), although the topic is different...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
call set VAR3=%%JAVA%VAR1%_HOME%%
```

should solve the problem, assuming `%` and hence `var` has a value `8`.

```
call set VAR3=%%JAVA%1_HOME%%
```

should also work in this instance.